# Mysql trigger for multiple tables updates

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I need to update the primary key of a table. This primary key exist in 3 other tables.

Simple example:

> model(ID_model, model)

`ID_model` exists in other tables:

`table motor(id-model, id-serie, id_year, etc)`  -- where `id_model`, `id_serie` and `id_year` are the primary_key
`table serie(id-serie, serie, id-model)` -- where `id_model` is a (foreign key)

How can I update the `ID_model` in table `model` and updating the `ID_model` in other tables together?

Comment: Use a foreign key constraint in the other tables with `on update cascade`. You need the InnoDB storage engine for this to work.

Comment: Updating a primary key is a strong clue for bad design, especially considering the name of the column you are trying to update ("ID_model" sounds like a surrogate key). I do hope this is only for a one-time hack (e.g. fix corrupted data after a disaster).